# Shading in different parts of the same shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon

[image]

[image]

I am creating a map of islands and I created a land shapefile using water shapefiles and therefore the land shapefile doesn't have any of the original attributes of the water shapefiles. I'm wondering if I can still shade in islands somehow?

Comment: I think you'll have to give them a 'land' or 'island' attribute in a TYPE column

Comment: how do I do that when the shapefile is one big polygon? with no unique IDs? I tried to look for tutorials but I found none.

Comment: It sounds like you have 1 giant 'single part' feature. If you run a the single part to multipart tool you can break up each polygon into its own feature... does that sound like the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options to shade both the islands and the water (sea, ocean etc).

**Shading part of a shapefile:**

**using symbologies**:

1.- the style options of QGIS are very varied, you can assign to your polygons a simple symbology or category, then in `symbol layer type` you assign `gradient`, and varying the options, for example, `gradient type: radial`, `reference point: centroid` and several `reference point1` values
[image]

If the layer has contiguous polygons as in the image it looks better if you assign in `coord mode: viewport`
[image]

2.- Another option is, assign in symbol layer type: `shapeburst fill`, then you can assign two colors for the degradation.

Or, most cooler, you can work with `color ramp`, editing the colors. You can assign multiple levels, Modify the set distance and blur strength parameters
[image]

3.- If this is not enough, you can assign additional effects in the style options, select `draw effects`, then click on the yellow star. In the dialog box try the different effects

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just only want to shade them in for symbology? Your image looks like this is done already for Northern Quebec. There is a symbology type called Inverted Polygons if that's all you need. Inverted polygons get a little funny with some CS though.

Why are you restricted to only using the water?

If you don't need the attributed of the islands or if you have a way to join them later, you might have to do something a bit more tedious like:

1. Draw a feature representing your study are (+ some extra) and call it 'land'
2. Use your water layer to clip 'land' with it
3. Single-to-multipart tool on the 'land'

Comment: There are islands that have points over them showing when they have been visited. I want to shade only those specific islands in.